# "hospitality": does it refer to the guest or the host?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

Is *hospitality* about being a good guest, or a good host?   Or is it a little bit of both?  Would it be the act of being a good host or is it different?

Comment: Mostly it's about being a good host, though some would enlarge the definition to include being a good guest as well.

Answer (score 4):

It's about being an accommodating and gracious host. Here are Merriam Webster's definitions:

a. generous and friendly treatment of visitors and guests : hospitable treatment

b. the activity of providing food, drinks, etc. for people who are the guests or customers of an organization